# Neel order and O(3) model

Tags: condensed-matter, critical-phenomena

The coarse grained fluctuations of the Neel order parameter in the half integer spin anti-ferromagnetic Heisenberg model is described by the O(3) non-linear sigma model with a strange berry phase term.

See for example : Eq-2 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0311326.pdf

I was wondering if someone could explain to me where the Berry phase term comes from.

Apart from the origin of the term, it is also not clear to me how such a Berry phase term is allowed in a Lagrangian without any periodicity in the time direction.

Thanks in advance for any inputs !